# How do I differentiate an inline function in matlab

Tags: matlab, inline, differentiation

suppose I write the following in matlab

```
c='x^2-6';
f=inline(c);
```

Then f will be an inline function. I can evaluate f at different values by entering

```
f(2)
f(5)
```

etc.

However, when I try `diff(f)` it doesnt return `2*x`. How would I be able to get `2*x` from `f`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use `inline` objects for symbolic math calculations. Use `sym` objects instead:

```
c= sym('x^2-6'); % creates the 'sym' object
subs(c,2) % calculates c(2)
diff(c);
```

Also note that `inline` [will be removed](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inline.html) in a future release

Answer (score 2):

You need the [MATLAB Symbolic Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/products/symbolic/). What you are describing is called symbolic differentiation. (There's also symbolic integration, etc.). The "normal" (non-symbolic) version of MATLAB is designed to do numerical calculations, not calculus or algebraic manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a symbolic method to take the function and the parameter as input from user and differentiate it.

```
clear;
clc;
v=input('Parameter :');%input for example 'x' and remember the quotes
syms(v);%symbolic variable : x in this case
y=input('function :');%example exp (x) ,not exp(y) or ay other variable
f=matlabFunction(y);%converts y to a command type function f
df = matlabFunction(diff(y)); %calculates the differentiation.
```

Now if you do something like f(1), it will show 2.71828 and df(1) will show 2.71828